# Cannot Remove Configuration Profile On iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, configuration-profiles

I worked at a company that used GOOD For Enterprise. I installed it on my iPhone 5s and now that I've left the company, would like to remove the profile. I've deleted the GOOD application, but I cannot remove the profile. There is no red "Remove" button like all of the tutorials show. I just did a full wipe and restored the phone with my iCloud profile and sure enough, it's still my one and only configuration profile on my phone. How do I get this off of here? Here are some images...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to wipe your phone and not restore from backup. Some configuration profiles allow the creator to prevent removal of the profile.

[Apple's configuration reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html) lists the following key the creator of the profile probably used:

> `PayloadRemovalDisallowed` -
>   Optional. Supervised only. If present and set to true, the user cannot delete the profile (unless the profile has a removal password and the user provides it).